# Cleaning up Line Features

Tags: routing, arcgis-10.2, intersection, linear-referencing, streets

I'm in the process of creating some routes for which I need left and right sections. I have an original streets feature class, which I used "copy parallels" on, and came up with something like the picture below.

I'm wondering if there is any tool that would clean up these roads, erase some dangles and intersecting lines. I've tried using the "trim" tool, but cannot come up with a standard length to trim.

Any ideas?

[image: Routes]

Using ArcGIS 10.2.1 Advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that you did a copy parallel equally on the left and the right of your original roads. So, in order to clean up a bit, you could

1. create a buffer polygon of the same size and dissolve all the
   boundaries. Because you have advanced licence, you can set up flat ends, it will be nicer in your case)
2. Use "feature to line" with your lines in order to
   split them where they intersect.
3. select by location the lines that
   share a line segment with your buffer polygons.

Comment: Should I make the buffer a tad smaller? So not all lines will share a segment with the buffer

Comment: no, it has to be exactly the same. sharing a line segment is more constraining than intersect : it means that the intersection with boundary must be a line (with intersect, the instersection can be point).